# Play Evolutions Resolve NullPointerException

Tags: heroku, playframework, playframework-1.x

I am using Play 1.2.4 and deploying to Heroku. When I deployed most recently, I had a mistake in my latest db evolution (it was trying to add a column that was already there). It failed and needed to be resolved so I just ran the `heroku run "play evolutions:resolve"` command.

I have tried also running `heroku restart` and then the above command but that didn't work either.

The error I get when I run the `heroku run "play evolutions:resolve"` command is

```
Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Djava.rmi.server.useCodebaseOnly=true
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
        at play.db.Evolutions.main(Evolutions.java:54)
```

How can I fix the production environment on heroku?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out I needed to add the `--%prod` flag.